# How to modify a binary file

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to modify some values in a binary file. This is how I create it and I read it:

```
void Save()
{
    User user1;
    user1.Rol=1;
    user1.Name="John";
    user1.Pass="test1";
    User user2;
    user2.Rol=2;
    user2.Name="Bob";
    user2.Pass="test2";

    QFile file("users.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        qDebug()<< "Error.";
        return;
    }
    QDataStream out(&file);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

    out << user1;
    out << user2;

    file.flush();
    file.close();
}
```

I want to know how I can modify a "John".

```
void Load()
{
    User user;

    QFile file("users.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug()<< "Error.";
        return;
    }
    QDataStream in(&file);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

    while(!in.atEnd())
    {
        in >> user;
        if(user.Name=="John")
        {
            qDebug() << user.Name << " is " << user.Rol << " and he has the password: " << user.Pass;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

The result is: "John"  is  1  and he has the password:  "test1". I want to modify this to: "John" and he has the password: "test3" but I don't know how I can modify it.

I've reading the documentation but I haven't found a good example.

Comment: Why are you using two different versions of QDataStream?

Comment: There are, of course, many ways. But you can read the source file and write to a temporary file. Write every record back unchanged until you want one changed, then write the new data. At the end delete the source file and rename the temporary file.

Comment: But if I have 10 000 users, it will be inefficient, right? Copy again 10 000 users would be too slow.

Comment: Computers are fast, so no, writing out the 10,000 users again probably wouldn't be "too slow" unless you're trying to do it many times per second for some reason. To do in-place modification typically requires fixed-sized records, and introduces a lot of complexity, for very little real-world gain. For very large data sets, you could also consider partitioning the data into separate files so you only have to re-write a subset of the records when a single record changes.

Comment: All that said, to actually modify it in-place requires that 1) you open the file in read-write mode (`QIODevice::ReadWrite`), and 2) use the `seek` method to move the file pointer to the data you want to overrwrite [fixed-sized records make this a lot simpler] and 3) write out the new data.

Comment: Do you know where I can find an example of this? I understand it but I have problems trying to apply it.